# ArcMap shutting down when I add rasters to a mosaic in foreground processing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, error, mosaic, background-geoprocessing

I'm trying to add rasters to a mosaic - I was initially trying to do this by background processing but I was receiveing an error - I've followed the advice of this article (http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38695) (turning off background processing/turning off the option to add geoprocessing results to the display) but I still can't get it to work - now instead of returning an error message ArcMap just shuts down with no warning.

Comment: You're experiencing a 'really bad crash'. Because BG is a separate process, when it crashes you don't lose ArcMap. When you turn BG off, ArcMap runs the tool and crashes. Which version are you running? I show the bug in the KB as fixed in 10.0sp2. If you're using newer than that it could be a new bug, probably data specific.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm running 10.2.2 so I guess it might be a new bug.

Comment: Besides the workaround suggested in the answers, I can only suggest logging a support ticket and submitting the data (if thats an option for you) so we can try to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

using Arcmap 10.1
you can use an alternative option:

1. add your all geo-refed raster in a new arcmap
2. define the projection properly in the data frame properties
3. Go to windows menu and click on image analysis.
4. In image analysis tool select all your rasters and click on mosaic button present in a window below named "processing".
5. A temporary raster add in table of contents, finally export it in tif or img format because you have 16bit data.

[image]